# How to make processing of a Pandas groupby object more efficient?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, group-by

"""
I have a data frame of million of rows that I did `.groupby()` on.

1. I'd like to retrieve the rows containing the nlargest value for each id and tissue combination.
2. Also, I need to generate another df containing the mean value for each id and tissue combination.
   Although I'm using a powerful Linux server, the process is being running for more that 24 hours. Therefore, I'm looking for a more efficient strategy. I spend hours on stackoverflow but I failed to apply the solutions to my particular problem.
   Thanks you in advance for helping me out.

"""

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['g1','g1','g1','g1','g2','g2','g2','g2','g2','g2'],\
                  'Trans':['g1.1','g1.2','g1.3','g1.4','g2.1','g2.2','g2.3','g2.2','g2.1','g2.1'],\
                  'Tissue': ['Lf','Lf','Lf','pc','Pol','Pol','Pol','Ant','Ant','m2'],\
                  'val': [0.0948,1.5749,1.8904,0.8673,2.1089,2.5058,4.5722,0.7626,3.1381,2.723]})
print('df')

df_highest = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)#brand new df that will contain the rows of interest
for grpID,data in df.groupby(['id','Tissue']):
    highest = data.nlargest(1,'val')
    df_highest.append(highest)

df_highest.to_csv('out.txt',sep='\t',index=False)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the largest value for each id and tissue combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the largest value for each id and tissue combination, try this code.

```
df_highest = df.loc[df.groupby(['id','Tissue'])['val'].idxmax()]
```

This will give you the mean of the id and Tissue combination.

```
df_mean = df.groupby(['id','Tissue']).agg({'val':np.mean})
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea for your time. I will give it a try. However, because I also need to generate another df containing the mean() value for each id and tissue combination, I'm looking for a more general technique so that I can use any function on it. Thanks

Comment: I think this will be faster because it doesn't iterate using a for loop. Depending on how many other df's you need, it might be faster to just write another line of code giving the mean.

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying the code above (df_highest = df.loc[df.groupby(['id','Tissue'])['val'].idxmax()]) but it's been running for about 12 hours on our server. Any other way to speed up the process? Thanks